# react-native installation in ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-virtual-device

```
smackuser@smackcoders:~/Documents/projects/Awesome$ react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.562 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android SDK Manager and under tools install Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.1. 
You can access SDK Manager by either typing android in your terminal or going to your android-sdk/tools directory and from there typing ./android